# Read Cross-domain url using getJson

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to read url using getJson. It doesn't fire neither the success function nor the error one.

```
var url = "http://demo.dreamacc.com/TextTable.json?callback=?";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                async: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (ooo) {
                    alert('hi');
                    alert(ooo);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('w');
                }
            });
```

but when I'm trying to read this url

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json?callback=?
```

it works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The endpoint (your requested URL, http://demo.dreamacc.com/TextTable.json) doesn't support JSONP returns.

You will not be able to retrieve data from this website using a JSONP request.

---

JSONP works by specifying to the remote server to wrap the JSON object within a function call (function name defined via the `callback` GET parameter). If the endpoint doesn't support this and modify its response appropriately, you will not be able to retrieve data from that site using JSONP.

**Examples:**

*Twitter (Supports JSONP):* [ [Normal JSON](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json) | [JSONP](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json?callback=jQueryJSONP2881233) ]

*demo.dreamacc (Doesn't support JSONP):* [ [Normal JSON](http://demo.dreamacc.com/TextTable.json) | [JSONP that doesn't work](http://demo.dreamacc.com/TextTable.json?callback=jQueryJSONP2881233) ]

As you can see, the demo.dreamacc.com endpoint doesn't wrap the response within a function call.

Comment: can the IIS be configured to support JSONP return?

Comment: It's not IIS. You have to handle that case with code. Depending on the technology used to serve the data (normal ASP.NET workflow, MVC2, WCF, PHP), you'll have to do some specific modifications to that code in order to support JSONP returns.

Comment: could u give me an example of those modifications please?

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly: This is more the subject of another question, as the answer will greatly differ based on the technology used.

Comment: here it is
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673725/support-jsonp-returns-in-asp-net