# support JSONP returns in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, jsonp, getjson

how to support JSONP returns in ASP.Net website for getJson calls?

```
var url = "http://demo.dreamacc.com/TextTable.json?callback=?";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (ooo) {
                alert('hi');
                alert(ooo);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('w');
            }
        });
```

the previous function doesn't fire the neither the success nor the error function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server you could write a handler which will return JSONP response:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // set the response content type to application/json
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        // generate some JSON that we would like to return to the client
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            status = "success"
        });

        // get the callback query string parameter
        var callback = context.Request["callback"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callback))
        {
            // if the callback parameter is present wrap the JSON
            // into this parameter => convert to JSONP
            json = string.Format("{0}({1})", callback, json);
        }

        // write the JSON/JSONP to the response
        context.Response.Write(json);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the generic handler will check for the presence of a `callback` querystring parameter and if specified it will wrap the JSON into this callback.

Now you could point the $.ajax call to this server side handler:

```
var url = "http://demo.dreamacc.com/MyHandler";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.success);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: is this url correct?
var url = "http://demo.dreamacc.com/MyHandler";

where to till it to read this file 
var url = "http://demo.dreamacc.com/TextTable.json?callback=?"

Comment: The url in my answer is now pointing to the generic handler that you need to write on the server in order to support JSONP. If the server doesn't support JSONP you cannot use it from a client side call. So the first thing you need to do is to add support for JSONP on the server.

Comment: if the domains are different, remember to add `CORS` support (`$.support.cors = true;`) to the call.

Comment: I added the handler and when pointing to it or to the file I need to read I receive no response, neither success nor fail.

Comment: @balexandre, the whole point of JSONP is that you don't need CORS.

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly, what happens when you try to invoke your generic handler directly in the browser address bar (`http://demo.dreamacc.com/MyHandler`)? Have you registered this handler in your web.config? If you have correctly setup the handler the first step is to be able to invoke it by typing the address directly in the browser. Normally you should see the JSON. And if you append a `?callback=foobar` query string parameter you should see JSONP in your browser. That's the first step that you should have working before even attempting to use any jQuery.

Comment: thanks a lot its working. how to allow this to read xml files?

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly, you could send XML content through JSONP but you cannot send directly XML files.

Comment: ok .. when I navigate to http://MyServerSideFile/httphandler?callback=ww the browser show: ww({"status":"success"}) but when I navigate to  http://MyServerSideFile/test.json?callback=ww the file content is shown with no padding and jquery is not able to read it

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly, what's `test.json`? Is it just a static file? If so then it is normal that there's no padding. You should serve this static json file through a managed handler (as the one shown in my answer) in order to add the padding, otherwise JSONP cannot work.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yeah it's a static file on the same server. Sorry but what do u mean by serving it?

Comment: This means that you should write a generic handler (as shown in my answer) which is reading the text file from the hard drive and wrapping it with a callback parameter so that the actual response is JSONP. Then on the client you should request `MyServerSideFile/httphandler?callback=ww` which wil return the contents of your static json file wrapped with the callback: `ww({... your static json contents come here ...})`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I wrote an httpModule to do that and it worked successfully when trying to read urls between two ports on my local machine but it failed when I uploaded the module to the server. The same thing happened when I worked with ur handler, local the handler is wrapped and read in jquery but on the server it didn't again :(

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I need a generic handler to read any file on the server. It will be pretty difficult to write a handler for each file I want to read

Comment: Why? Simply pass the filename as parameter to this handler in addition to the callback. Of course you should make sure to sanitize this parameter so that it is accessing only files from a specific folder, to avoid exposing ANY file from the server.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ok I created it and it worked fine when testing it on my local machine. When I test it on the server this is the result 
http://testhandler.rakjed.com/httphandler?callback&site=l&filepath=test.json

Comment: Yes, your server seems to send 404 not found status code. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the handler is on the server and the file that it should read is on it. Why is sends not found status?